# Using Redux state in React component

Tags: react.js, redux

I am using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and have a general-purpose `ui-slice` that I use for UI states that I need globally.

In particular I have few components that need to know the current width of the window to conditionally render some content. So I made this reducer:

```js
acknowledgeScreenWidth(state, action) {
    state.screenWidth = action.payload.screenWidth;
},
```

I dispatch against this reducer only in one place, in a layout component, like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const updateWidth = () => dispatch(uiActions.acknowledgeScreenWidth({ screenWidth: window.innerWidth }));
    updateWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
  }, []);
```

And then in the components where I need the current width I have:

```js
const screenWidth = useSelector(store => store.ui.screenWidth);
const isSmall = screenWidth < 768;
```

Which works because every time `screenWidth` changes, the component rerenders and `isSmall` is redeclared.

However the components also have other states and there is no need to redeclare `isSmall` every time they rerender. (furthermore, the window width is likely to be always the same from the beginning to the end)

So I wonder if creating a local state:

```js
const screenWidth = useSelector(store => store.ui.screenWidth);
const [isSmall, setIsSmall] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsSmall(screenWidth < 768)
}, [screenWidth]);
```

Or memoizing `isSmall`:

```
const screenWidth = useSelector(store => store.ui.screenWidth);
const isSmall = useMemo(() => screenWidth < 768, [screenWidth]);
```

Could be a better approach, or is actually an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Performance

I don't think that you need to change the approach you are taking with `isSmall`, it is very cheap to create that variable each render. The other two approaches you posted would actually be worse in performance. You can read further on this [wonderful blog](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) by Kent C. Dodds.

Ultimately, if it really bothers you, you should measure it. Profile the renders and see which way it is faster.

### `useEffect`

The code you posted is potentially buggy. The dependency array is missing some dependencies:

```javascript
useEffect(() => {
    const updateWidth = () => dispatch(uiActions.acknowledgeScreenWidth({ screenWidth: window.innerWidth }));
    updateWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
  }, [dispatch, uiActions]);
```

I think that you should probably use the `useLayoutEffect` hook because I think that your app might flicker twice before setting the new width on resizing, but I am just guessing since I don't have the reproducible example. Usually, when you are dealing with layout transformations, you would use this hook.

### The approach

Your approach looks good to me.

Comment: After writing the question I reasoned too that the other two approaches couldn't perform better, but I thought that maybe there was some best practice to follow. Anyway I read about `useLayoutEffect` and it fits perfectly in this case. Thanks for this amazing discovery

Comment: I'm glad it helped @SheikYerbouti